# Paginating a Nested Resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating a ticket booking app as my sample project using Ruby on Rails 4.1. Three are three models - Events, Tickets and Bookings. Events have many tickets and bookings. Tickets have many bookings and they belong to events. Bookings belongs to events and tickets.

The routes file looks like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  resources :charges

  root 'events#index'

  resources :events do
    resources :tickets
    resources :bookings
  end
end
```

Now, I used the will_paginate gem to organize the index pages of Events and Bookings. In the case of events, it was pretty straightforward and pagination works fine. However, when it comes to bookings, which is nested resource, the index page has paginated links but, all the pages show all the booking entries. There is no pagination happening at all.

The Bookings Controller looks like:

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:index, :destroy]

  def index
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @bookings =@event.bookings.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
  end
```

and the Bookings index:

```
<h2>All Bookings</h2>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>Buyer Name</th>
                  <th>Email Address</th>
                  <th>Ticket Type</th>
                  <th>No. of Tickets</th>
                  <th>Amount</th>
                  <th></th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <% @event.bookings.each do |booking| %> 
              <tr> 
                  <td><%= booking.buyer_name %></td>
                  <td><%= booking.email %></td>
                  <td><% unless booking.ticket.blank? %>
                        <%= booking.ticket.ticket_name rescue nil %>
                      <% else %>
                         No Ticket
                      <% end %>
                  </td>
                  <td><%= booking.order_quantity %></td>
                  <td><% unless booking.ticket.blank? %>
                        <%= number_to_currency(booking.total_amount) %>
                    <% else %>
                      No Amount
                    <% end %>
                  </td>                  
                  <td><%= link_to "Delete", event_booking_path(@event, booking), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: "btn btn-link" %></td>
            <% end %>
          </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
<%= will_paginate @bookings %>
<%= link_to "Back to Event", event_path(@event), class: "btn btn-link" %>
<%= link_to "All Bookings", event_bookings_path(@event), class: "btn btn-link" %>
```

When I hover over the paginated links, the correct URL structure is maintained. Is the table that I'm using coming in the way by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paginated list of events is stored in the `@bookings` variable, but in your table you are iterating over the `@event.bookings` collection which will be unpaginated.

Change this

```
<% @event.bookings.each do |booking| %>
```

to this

```
<% @bookings.each do |booking| %>
```

Comment: Thanks. Even if I wasn't trying to paginate, I guess I can use '@bookings' instead of '@event.bookings' to get the desired result when using a block?

Comment: Yes absolutely. You may want to do other things aside from pagination (e.g. sorting, filtering, etc.) to the `@bookings` collection, so it's probably a good idea to get in the habit of utilizing the instance variable rather than the collection method of the `@event` variable.

Comment: That's a valuable piece of advice. Much appreciated!